# How to execute command-line arguments with parameters in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameters, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to compare two folders using a third party comparison tool called UltraCompare. The following line calls the program and opens two files... but this doesn't do anything except open them, plus it doesn't work properly for *folders*.

```
Process.Start("C:\\Program Files\\IDM Computer Solutions\\UltraCompare\\uc.exe", 
textBoxContents1 + " " + textBoxContents2);
```

I'd like to use the following command line call which opens two folders, runs a comparison on them, and stores the results in output.txt: **uc -d -dmf "c:\dir1" "c:\dir2" -o "c:\output.txt"**

Also, I'd need to use variables for the folders instead of hardcoding the paths.

How can I work that into my C# code?

**UPDATE 1:**

I've modified my code according to your suggestions:

```
var p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\IDM Computer Solutions\\UltraCompare\\uc.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("-d -dmf \"{0}\" \"{1}\" -o c:\\output2.txt",
textBoxContents1, textBoxContents2);
p.Start();
```

I'm wondering why the third line containing the arguments still doesn't work...

**UPDATE 2:**

My mistake. It is working now!! Just doesn't display the folders in UltraCompare but it is still writing and saving the output. Thanks guys!

Comment: Are you asking how to concatenate strings?

Comment: For your folders problem, quote all your string: `Process.Start("""C:\\Program Files\\file.exe""")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
yourProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = " .....";
```

Sample

```
var p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\IDM Computer Solutions\\UltraCompare\\uc.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("-d -dmf {0} {1} -o c:\output.txt",textBoxContents1,   textBoxContents2);
p.Start();
```

Comment: this works... except it's screwing up the locations of both folders! I modified the third line a bit to use the variables for the folder locations: **p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-d -dmf" + textBoxContents1 + " " + textBoxContents2 + "-o c:\\output.txt";** Do you think this could be the problem?

Comment: i'am happy to help you user1985189, you can format your string

Comment: the file locations, as specified by textBoxContents1 and 2, are C:\Toms Work\WebSite1 and C:\Toms Work\WebSite2 but it looks like it's trying to open **C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\Work\WebSite2-o** and **C:\Toms** instead...

Comment: I tried your formatted code but it gives me a message from UltraCompare saying "unsupported operation" and won't open at all. :(

Comment: I belive you need to add double quotes within the path name.   String.Format("-d -dmf \"{0}\" \"{1}\" -o c:\output.txt",textBoxContents1

Comment: @TYY well that takes care of the "unsupported operation" message, but it doesn't open the files now it's just an empty window

Comment: My suggestion to you would be to reun the exact string in command prompt see if you get the expected result, get the value you retrieve from the string format and compare that they match.

Answer (score 5):

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
{
   FileName = @"C:\Program Files\IDM Computer Solutions\UltraCompare\uc.exe",
   Arguments = String.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\"", textBoxContents1, textBoxContents2)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use quotation marks for arguments, too!
If any of `textBoxContents1` or `textBoxContents2` contains spaces, you are busted!

Comment: do you mean that this won't work if the file path contains spaces? such as the space between "Toms" and "Work" in C:\Toms Work\WebSite1?